# Using SQL count of multiple column values in Snowflake and transpose table output

Tags: sql, group-by, count, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that has 5 cols that looks like so (example):

```
Conf_1   | Conf_2   | Conf_3   | Conf_4   | Conf_5
High       No Match   Perfect    No Match   Perfect
High       Perfect    Review     No Match   Perfect
No Match   No Match   Perfect    Medium     Low
Perfect    Medium     No Match   Low        Medium
Low        Low        Review     Medium     High
Medium     No Match   No Match   Perfect    High
```

The values consist of Perfect, High, Medium, Low, No Match, and Review. Some columns contains all values and some only contain one or two of the values.

I would like to count the number of times each value shows up for each column - transpose the table into the 6 values (Perfect - Review) as the Rows and then have the count for each of the 5 Conf fields.

Desired output looks like so:

Here the confidence column is the disctinct values from the combined conf_1,conf_2......conf_5

```
Confidence | Conf_1 Count  | Conf_2 Count.....| Conf_5
Perfect      25               40               50 
High         25               Null             50
Medium       5                Null             50
Low          100              100              Null
No Match     4                5                Null
Review       Null             15               Null
```

Comment: can you explian what is this confidence column in your desired output

Comment: essentially count(conf_1), count(conf_2) and group by each respective field to get the number of times "Perfect" shows up vs the number of times "High" shows up. If that makes sense @trillion

Comment: so counf_1 is just for perfect and counf_2 is just for High and so on ? I think you need case when for all those

Comment: No, sorry - I would want to count the number of times each row value (high, med, low, etc) shows up per column then transpose into the desired output as shown above

Comment: can you show me what does my answer returns ? is that what you want, see below

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
confidence,
count(case when Confidence = 'Perfect' then 1 else 0) end as conf_1,
count(case when Confidence = 'High' then 1 else 0) end as conf_2,
count(case when Confidence = 'Medium' then 1 else 0) end as conf_3,
count(case when Confidence = 'Low' then 1 else 0) end as conf_4,
count(case when Confidence = 'No Match' then 1 else 0) end as conf_5,
count(case when Confidence = 'Review' then 1 else 0) end as conf_6

from table
group by 1
```

You can build confidence using something like:

```
select * from (
select conf_1 as confidence from table
union 
select conf_2 as col from table
union
select conf_3 as col from table
union
select conf_4 as col from table
union 
select conf_5 as col from table
union
select conf_6 as col from table

) t where confidence is not null
order by confidence
```

Comment: @Dinho is that waht you want ?

Comment: No quite - I don't have a col named 'Confidence' - I wanted to make that based on the conf_1 - conf_5 fields.

Comment: why don't you format your question correctly first then :)

Comment: Its based on the original table - I want to create a new field called confidence that differs from that table - thought the question was clear but thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dinho i added a way to created the condfidence

Comment: Awesome - and then would I join to that query or how would I add your first query to that? Since now confidence is a new field - I think what you sent would work. Thank you!

Comment: i believe you will have to create a CTE and join each conf_1,conf_2 .... to confidence and then use the query one on that. Would be great if you can share the output / final query once you are done. Would be interesting for me as well